# Java Pattern Matcher is not working for regex as expected

Tags: java, regex

```
1)  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("34238");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("6003 Honore Ave Suite 101 Sarasota Florida,
   34238");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }

2)  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("34238");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
```

Output for the above code is: **ok**

But the following code is not printing anything:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("6003 Honore Ave Suite 101 Sarasota Florida, 34238");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
```

What is the reason for this not to print **ok**? I am using the same pattern here also.

Comment: Why not using `"6003 Honore Ave Suite 101 Sarasota Florida,
   34238".contains("34238")` ?

Comment: It is US zip code format.We are not sure will get the same

Comment: Finally I have to find weather that sentence has US zip code or not

Comment: Which of the two blocks produces ok?

Comment: 1st and 2nd blocks

Comment: @PSR, your code works as it should work. The regex you are using matches only lines with `12345` or `12345-1234`. Check my answer for more details

Answer (score 2):

The code is good and working as expected. In the `2)` and `3)` block in your question you are using the same regex but different input strings.

However, if you just want to check if a string must contain a US zip code, then the problem is that your regex is using anchors, so you are only matching lines that starts and finish with a zip code.

The strings that matches your regex are like `34238` or `34238-1234` and won't match `something 12345 something`.

If you remove the anchors, then you will match `whatever 12345 whatever`:

```
// Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$");
//                                    ^--------- Here -------^
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("6003 Honore Ave Suite 101 Sarasota Florida, 34238");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

Btw, if you just want to check if a string contains a zip code, then you can use `String.matches(..)`, like this:

```
String str = "6003 Honore Ave Suite 101 Sarasota Florida, 34238";
if (str.matches(".*[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?.*")) {
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

**[IDEOne demo](https://ideone.com/NuoTjM)**

Answer (score 2):

Although the pattern is the same, the input strings are different:

- In your second example, you are matching a string consisting entirely of a zip code, so you get a match for `^...$` expression
- The second example does not start with the zip code, so the `^` anchor prevents your regex from matching.

`^` and `$` anchors are used when you want your expression to match the entire input line. When you want to match at the beginning, keep `^` and remove `$`; when you want to match at the end, remove `^` and keep `$`; when you want to match anywhere inside the string, remove both anchors.